# Как обнулить элементы которые не принадлежат срезу?

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть образный массив :

```
 myarray = np.array(([1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]))
```

Я хочу обнулить элементы которые не принадлежат срезу, как к ним обратиться и модифицировать?

Сделал срез :`slice = myarray[1:5:1]`

Получаю на выходе массив :

```
[[3 4]
 [5 6]
 [7 8]]
```

Таким образом необходимо обнулить элементы

```
[1,2]
```

Понимаю, что можно напрямую обратиться к элементам по индексам, но меня интересует вариант чтобы модифицировать массив без доступа по индексу, так как хотел бы изменить срез.

Comment: "Сделал срез: `slice = myarray[1,5,1]`" - выдает ошибку `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed`. Поясните какой именно срез вы хотите сделать и приведите в вопросе желаемый результат

Comment: Исправил и дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение - воспользуйтесь вспомогательной матрицей (булевой маской):

```
slice_ = slice(1,5,1)

mask = np.ones_like(myarray, dtype=bool)

mask[slice_] = False

myarray[mask] = 0
```

результат:

```
In [252]: myarray
Out[252]:
array([[0, 0],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])

In [253]: mask
Out[253]:
array([[ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False]])
```

PS не используйте в качестве имен переменных/объектов наименования  встроенных функций/классов, таких как [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)!